# Esperando por extração de áudio remoto em Java

Tags: java, android, ios, windows-phone, servidor

Em meu projeto de faculdade tenho uma pequena API em Java que extrai o áudio de arquivos de vídeos, onde o é passado a URL do vídeo e é devolvido um arquivo em MP3, até aí tudo bem.

Gostaria de manter um servidor realizando as tarefas de baixar o vídeo e depois extrair o áudio e do outro lado um cliente esperando o link para o download do arquivo em MP3. Isso ocorreria da seguinte forma: o usuário informa o link, o servidor baixa nele mesmo e extrai o áudio, após isso, e disponibilizado o áudio para o usuário.

Mas como eu faria isso no cliente? Eu gostaria de implementar o cliente no Android, mas como mantê-lo esperando o download do vídeo e extração para depois entregar o link do MP3 para download? É como se fosse um *listener*, mas há uma comunicação entre cliente e servidor. RMI, SOAP, WSDL? Gostaria de uma solução que não impactasse numa possível implementação para iOS ou WP.

Comment: Você pode usar GCM para notificar o dispositivo assim que a extração terminar. Enquanto isso pode manter uma tela de espera (`ProgressDialog`) ou outra forma de mostrar que está pendente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que deixar o cliente aguardar o processamento do áudio não é uma boa ideia, pois você deve considerar arquivos maiores e provavelmente preocupar-se com isso do lado do cliente o que lhe forçaria a implementar algo nativo e isso iria contra a sua preocupação sobre o projeto ser multiplataforma.

A opção do Jan Cássio é muito boa, pois você já enviaria o link para o cliente e faria esse tratamento sobre o arquivo ter sido processado ou não.

Existem outras formas de fazer isso mas cada uma delas exige mais complexidade na implementação.

Se as dicas dos colegas acima não forem suficientes reabriremos as possibilidades.

Atte;

Answer (score 1):

Você pode manter a comunicação ativa entre dois pontos (cliente e servidor), através de sockets, no seu caso, uma solução mais simples e barata de implementar funciona tão bem quanto.

Pensando de um modo simples, você já pode gerar o link de acesso ao áudio, a partir do momento em que o video for entregue para o servidor processar, mesmo sem ter o audio pronto. Quando o link for acessado, você pode retornar um status do audio (processing, complete, error, ou qualquer coisa do tipo) e desta forma você nunca vai ter o link quebrado, o cliente não vai ficar esperando uma resposta do servidor e o servidor só vai responder por demanda. Quando o audio estiver pronto, ou você retorna um link para ele, ou retorna o location alterado para o audio. Como você vai implementar o cliente (imagino), é melhor retornar um dado estruturado (json, xml) com o resultado/status do audio,por que da mais flexibilidade pra você fazer o que quiser com isso.

Uma boa referência é o Dropbox, experimente colocar um arquivo bem pesado na sua pasta local do Dropbox, deixe-o sincronizando e crie um link de compartilhamento, quando você tenta abrir o link antes do arquivo estar pronto, ele retorna no browser uma página falando que o arquivo está "subindo". Se quiser ir mais a fundo, experimente fazer isso usando a API do Dropbox para você ver o que é retornado pelo servidor dele.

Answer (score 0):

As vezes soluções simples podem ser eficaz, eu pensei em algo extremamente simples, se eu fosse você além de pedir a URL do vídeo eu pediria o e-mail do usuário, e também no lado do servidor abriria um servidor http(apache, ISS, etc).

Para cado vídeo recebido de um usuário eu enviaria um email com o link de download após a extração em MP3, você vai gerar uma url única pode ser randômica ou incremental para cada email com link enviado, você vai precisar do servidor http para cada cliente poder se conectar e baixar os áudios.

Os clientes não possuem impacto algum, só precisam ter um browser ler o email e clicar no seu link.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Realmente é uma solução simples, vou estudá-la melhor. Abraço!